# How to accept real payments in Authorize.net in iOS?

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I have integrated Authorize payment gateway in my iOS code, Everything works perfect in sandbox account , now I want to live the app with real transaction. I followed this link for initial set up

http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/

But there is no documentation for real payment. I have Merchant login also. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Have you set the environment to production instead of sandbox?

Comment: Great Thanks... [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_LIVE]; this worked...

Comment: @rhldr I am all set now but my client is not happy with enabling mobile device ID every time in portal because When we do marketing of contents, will the approving time wouldn't cause a delay in purchase? (or) some time the user might change the decisions. This is the reason I am asking. Is there any option apart from enabling device every time?

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment from Sandbox to Live to begin accepting payments.

[AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_LIVE]

Comment: I am all set now but my client is not happy with enabling mobile device ID every time in portal because When we do marketing of contents, will the approving time wouldn't cause a delay in purchase? (or) some time the user might change the decisions. This is the reason I am asking. Is there any option apart from enabling device every time?

Comment: Each new device must be approved only once and then the user must login using the Login ID and Password.  It will then time out after 60 minutes of non-use or 8 hours.

Please note that the SDK is intended for use where the merchant holds the device and is accepting payments from the customer face to face.  It's not intended to be used by the customer on their own device.

Comment: I want it to be used by customers on their own device, Any suggestions's?